# How to use a text as a Button in Android

Tags: android

I want to use a text as a button in Android. Suppose I have one text like 'Register'. I want to use this text as a button means when i will click in the text, it will open the Registration Screen. I am using XML for developing the UI and i am doing it for Android Tablet Application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the following property in the xml of TextView:

```
android:background="#dadada"
    android:clickable="true"
```

Now in the java src file recieve this TextView and set  OnClickListener.

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perform your action here  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Used Below Code.

In XML file Textview assign this property

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and in java side OnClickListener used.

Comment: But when i am running it is showing the application has stopped Unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML file use this for your TextView :

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Then in your source set on click listener :

```
TextView txtRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegister);
txtRegister .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
          your codes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the method of the `View` to call with the following attribute in your xml layout:

```
android:onClick="yourMethodName"
```

The context that this `View` is used in is the class that should have this method (the context is usually your `Activity`)

For example:

```
<TextView
  android:onClick="register"
  android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_parent"/>
```

You would need to have the following method in your context (again, your `Activity`):

```
public void register(View v) {
  //
}
```

This is something you can do with ANY `View` type.  Here is a link to the [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use a Text as a Button is BINDING.

First you need to enable binding:
Go to

> build.gradle(Module)

Now add the following snippet inside "android"

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
```

Now click on "SYNC NOW". This will enable binding.

Now you have to create object of binding

```
ActivityMainBinding binding;
```

if ID of your TextView is "textView", then you can use it as a button by using this command:

```
binding.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
        }
    });
```